# Ошибка при подтверждении регистрации dj_rest_auth + django_allauth

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, jwt, аутентификация, django-allauth

У меня проблема с регистрацией:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: TemplateResponseMixin requires either a definition of 'template_name' or an implementation of 'get_template_names()'
```

Полный текст ошибки:

```
[12/Jan/2023 17:23:17] "POST /api/v1/dj-rest-auth/registration/ HTTP/1.1" 201 7602
Internal Server Error: /api/v1/dj-rest-auth/registration/account-confirm-email/Mg:1pFyU8:IOAVKLfedGheMRBylb0IChaH2nxp6DuGZ5ZteB3Y-VI/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\blogapi\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "E:\blogapi\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "E:\blogapi\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 103, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\blogapi\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 142, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\blogapi\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 226, in get
    return self.render_to_response(context)
  File "E:\blogapi\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 199, in render_to_response
    template=self.get_template_names(),
  File "E:\blogapi\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 211, in get_template_names
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: TemplateResponseMixin requires either a definition of 'template_name' or an implementation of 'get_template_names()'
[12/Jan/2023 17:23:46] "GET /api/v1/dj-rest-auth/registration/account-confirm-email/Mg:1pFyU8:IOAVKLfedGheMRBylb0IChaH2nxp6DuGZ5ZteB3Y-VI/ HTTP/1.1" 500 84984
```

Пишу проект на django rest framework. Установил dj-rest-auth и django-allauth для аутентификации. В installed_apps:
*"django.contrib.sites",
"rest_framework",
"rest_framework.authtoken",
"allauth",
"allauth.account",
"allauth.socialaccount",
"dj_rest_auth",
"dj_rest_auth.registration"*
В конфигурацию добавил настройки REST_FRAMEWORK, EMAIL_BACKEND, SITE_ID, миграции применены. Использую аутентификацию по JWT. За шаблон настройки брал книгу Вильяма Винсента "Django для API 3.1" (уже не самая свежая). Пробовал с самыми новыми пакетами на сегодня (12.01.2023) и с версиями, использующимися в книге (конец 2020 года). Причем регистрация проходит успешно, в БД появляются пользователи, токены для них, можно залогиниться под этими аккаунтами, но когда приходит письмо, прохожу по ссылке и выдается ошибка о каком-то шаблоне. Подскажите, пожалуйста, если кто сталкивался с подобным. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: @andreymal, добавил

Comment: В документации dj-rest-auth есть объяснение, почему оно не работает и что с этим делать https://dj-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html

Comment: @andreymal, спасибо